# Convergence of a Sequence by definition. Approach issue

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

*Definition*: So according to the definition a sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent to some $x$ if:
For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $K(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ if $n \ge K(\epsilon)$, we have $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$.

a) Now my approach of showing if the given sequence is convergent (works for fairly obvious ones) is to show that for an arbitrary given $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $K(\epsilon)$. Then, based on the choice of $n \ge K(\epsilon)$ derive the conclusion.

b) In books I have seen the other approach, for an arbitrary given $\varepsilon > 0$ following from the conclusion $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$ make simplifications to get a $f(n) < \varepsilon$ then claim that this will be the case only if $K(\epsilon)$ is taken such that $g(K) < \epsilon$ and then for all $n \ge K(\epsilon)$ the statement will hold true.

I am wondering, if my approach is totally wrong? I can't see it right now because in my head I think, that I am following the definition. I am asking this because I have got some results that I don't like e.g., a sequence converges to $0$, where it should not in reality.

Let's bring an example of both approaches:
$\lim(\frac{1}{n+1})$

a) For $\varepsilon > 0$, by Archimedian property we can take $K(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K(\varepsilon) > \frac{1}{\varepsilon} - 1$. Then for any $n \ge K(\epsilon)$ we would have $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1$ i.e. $n + 1 > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}, \frac{1}{n+1} < \varepsilon$. Since, $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, then by definition $(3.1.3)$ we have that $\lim (y_n) = 0$

b) Let $\varepsilon > 0$ to find $K(\epsilon)$, we first note that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then
$|\frac{1}{n+1}-0| < |\frac{1}{n}| = \frac{1}{n}$

Now if we choose $K(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{K(\varepsilon)} < \varepsilon$, then for $n \ge K(\varepsilon)$ we would have $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$. So, the sequence converges to $0$.

Again, I am asking this since I clearly struggle to see the invalidity of "my approach". It would be immensely appreciated if you point out the logic flaws to me.

Comment: So, I figured out that basically the problem with the first approach is that in some cases, while moving from the choice of $K(\varepsilon)$ I can get stuck, unless the sequence is simplified beforehand. For example, in the solution $(a)$ that I provided I asserted that for a given $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $K(\varepsilon) > \frac{1}{\varepsilon} - 1$ which is true. However, for certain values of $\varepsilon$ I am in no position to continue my argument since I never considered the sign of the right hand side expression in the first place.

Comment: What is f(n) and $K(\epsilon)? I've just seen many books use $n>n_1$ as part of the definition. also, what is the main question here, are you asking for clarification on the way to prove a sequence converges to a certain number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing invalid with your approach.

The difference between a) and b) is not one of right or wrong, validity versus invalidity.

The difference is one of *logical formality* versus *mathematical strategy*.

What you wrote is logically correct, one must...

> *...show that for any arbitrary given $\epsilon>0$ there is a $K(\epsilon)$*.

However the question arises: once $\epsilon>0$ is given...

- ***... how do you find an appropriate $K(\epsilon)$?***

Of course you cannot just pick $K(\epsilon)$ randomly out of a hat. You might pick an *inappropriate* value of $K(\epsilon)$, for which the implication "$n \ge K(\epsilon) \implies |x_n-x|<\epsilon$" is simply false. So you must somehow pick an *appropriate* value, namely one for which that implication is true.

Which brings up the next question:

- What is a good *mathematical strategy* for finding an appropriate $K(\epsilon)$?

What item (b) is suggesting is an actual strategy. Let me fill out that strategy a little bit.

Namely, you start by writing out the inequality
$$|x_n-x|<\epsilon
$$
You should substitute whatever numerical value for $x$ is given, and you should imagine that the value of $\epsilon$ has been fixed. The *formula* for $x_n$ has also been given, and you should substitute that formula into the inequality.

Thinking of $n$ as an unknown, the strategy is that you attempt to *solve* this inequality, hopefully obtaining a solution of the form $n > K(\epsilon)$.

---

Let me go through your example of $\lim\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$. My one issue with the solution you present in part a) is this: where did that formula $\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$ come from? Somehow I doubt that you just picked it randomly out of a hat. My guess is that this example is so easy that you simply solved the inequality. Maybe one can solve the inequality very quickly in one's head without writing out the intermediate steps, thereby hiding the mathematical strategy. I am not a proponent of hiding mathematical strategies, though, so let me write out the whole solution very carefully:
\begin{align*}
& |x_n-x| < \epsilon \\
& \left| \frac{1}{n+1} - 0 \right| < \epsilon
\\
\iff & \left| \frac{1}{n+1} \right| < \epsilon
\\
\iff & \frac{1}{n+1} < \epsilon \qquad\text{(because $\frac{1}{n+1} > 0$)}
\\
\iff & 1 < (n+1) \epsilon \qquad\text{(because $n+1>0$)}
\\
\iff & \frac{1}{\epsilon} < n+1 \qquad\text{(because $\epsilon > 0$)}
\\
\iff & \frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1 < n
\\
\iff & n > \underbrace{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1}_{K(\epsilon)}
\end{align*}
And there you go, you have solved the inequality, and using your solution you know what formula to use for $K(\epsilon)$. The way this proof has been written, using bi-implications at every step, you can then start with the assumption $n > K(\epsilon)$ and work up through the bi-implications to reach the desired conclusion $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$, and the proof is done.

---

In general it is not always very easy to solve the inequality with bi-implications. Furthermore it is not *necessary* to solve the inequality with bi-implications: once you have found an appropriate formula for $K(\epsilon)$ your remaining job is to prove just the one-way implication $n > K(\epsilon) \implies |x_n-x| < \epsilon$. Therefore, while bi-implications are certainly safe, in the general strategy a bi-implication is more than you need, you simply have to make sure that at each step working down from $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ to $n > K(\epsilon)$, the backwards implication $\impliedby$ is true.

Answer (score 1):

You said in a comment that

> for certain values of $\varepsilon$ I am in no position to continue my argument since I never considered the sign of the right hand side expression in the first place

I think writing a concrete example of $K(\varepsilon)$ should help.

In your approach, you can take $K(\varepsilon)=\lceil\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rceil$ as follows :

*Proof* : For $\varepsilon > 0$, take $K(\varepsilon)=\lceil\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rceil$. Then for any $n \ge K(\epsilon)$ we would have $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1$ i.e. $n + 1 > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}, \frac{1}{n+1} < \varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, the sequence, by the definition, converges to $0$.$\ \square$